# Rowcount for T-SQL Merge statement SCD2 type?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge, sql-server-2008-r2

I have written t-SQL Merge statement for SCD type2, its working fine but, I want audit information for number of rows inserted, updated.
here is Ex:

```
insert into dbo.MergegeSCD2
(id, firstname, lastname, CREATE_DTTM, MODIF_DTTM, ARCHV_FLAG, EffectiveFrom, EffectiveTo,  CurrentFlag)
select 
    id, firstname, lastname, CREATE_DTTM, MODIF_DTTM, ARCHV_FLAG, EffectiveFrom, EffectiveTo,  CurrentFlag
from 
(
--DECLARE @SummaryOfChanges TABLE(Change VARCHAR(20))

MERGE dbo.MergegeSCD2 TT
using dbo.MergegeSCD1 SS
on ss.id=tt.id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
              INSERT (id, firstname, lastname, CREATE_DTTM, MODIF_DTTM, ARCHV_FLAG, EffectiveFrom, EffectiveTo,  CurrentFlag)
              values (id, firstname, lastname, CREATE_DTTM, MODIF_DTTM, ARCHV_FLAG,'1800-01-01', NULL ,1)
WHEN MATCHED and tt.[CurrentFlag] = 1 
       AND exists
                (select ss.id, ss.firstname, ss.lastname, ss.CREATE_DTTM, ss.MODIF_DTTM, ss.ARCHV_FLAG
                except
                select tt.id, tt.firstname, tt.lastname, tt.CREATE_DTTM, tt.MODIF_DTTM, tt.ARCHV_FLAG
                )
      THEN UPDATE set tt.[CurrentFlag] = 0
                        , tt.[EffectiveTo] = ss.[MODIF_DTTM]
       OUTPUT $Action Action_Taken
              , ss.id, ss.firstname, ss.lastname, ss.CREATE_DTTM, ss.MODIF_DTTM, ss.ARCHV_FLAG
              , ss.[MODIF_DTTM] AS [EffectiveFrom]
              , NULL AS [EffectiveTo]
              ,1 AS [CurrentFlag]
)
AS MERGE_OUT
WHERE MERGE_OUT.Action_Taken = 'UPDATE';
select @@ROWCOUNT
```

I got updated records using `select @@ROWCOUNT`, but I am struggling for `inserted records`. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
OUTPUT $action, inserted.Column_Name
```

at the end of the MERGE.
E.g. this is what we do whenever we use MERGE.  We first declare a table variable:

```
DECLARE @tableVar TABLE 
(MergeAction VARCHAR(20), 
InsertedID INT)
```

Then at the end of the MERGE ad:

```
OUTPUT
      $action, inserted.Column_name 'inserted' INTO @tableVar
```

Comment: Hi @Mangal Pardeshi, in the above code I have commented line, where I try to use table variable but it saying error. where should I declare and in OUT clause there are some some more columns coming in, so how to insert into?

Comment: You should declare the table before you MERGE statement, should be at the very top, In your case even before the INSERT.

Comment: Hi @Mangal Pardeshi, thanks for the reply. I tried as you mentioned but when I insert into @tablevariable it saying error. for Ex: `OUTPUT $Action Action_Taken  INTO @tableVar
              , ss.id, ss.firstname, ss.lastname, ss.CREATE_DTTM, ss.MODIF_DTTM, ss.ARCHV_FLAG
              , ss.[MODIF_DTTM] AS [EffectiveFrom]
              , NULL AS [EffectiveTo]
              ,1 AS [CurrentFlag]
)`

Answer (score 0):

For tracking inserted rows in SCD2 Merge Statement, I usually take following script after the Merge Statement:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.table_target WHERE valid_from = @begin_in_date AND loadid = @loadid`

So far, didn't found a better solution.